# Is there a reason for slow speed of my internal SSD?

Tags: macos, ssd, high-sierra

I have an iMac from 2010 with a 250GB internal SSD running High Sierra. I just ran the following from the terminal:

```
time mkfile 4000000000 test

real    2m25.556s
user    0m0.910s
sys     1m26.219s

time cp test /Applications/

real    5m31.669s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m3.319s
```

I'm getting write speeds from the first test of around 25 MB per sec. and even less for the cp command.  This seems very slow to me but maybe it was normal in 2010. Do these numbers signify anything or are they normal considering the age?

Comment: Is the SSD the primary drive or did you replace the optical drive?

Comment: This is the original drive that came with my iMac and yes it is my primary drive.

Comment: Those speeds are very slow for an SSD.

Comment: I got performance back on my SSD by running Disk Sensei's "manual trim" option - but mine is an aftermarket Samsung, not an Apple original. idk whether it would be recommended for an OEM drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. I hadn't heard of this tool but its worth a try.